# Microsoft expression Web 4 Super Preview webpage navigation

Tags: cross-browser, expression-blend, superpreview

I am unable to click the submit button in the webpage while viewing it in the expression to navigate to next page. Do any body have the same issue? or how go to next page?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are having trouble interacting with the page in SuperPreview. I had the same problem too. All you need to do is to click on the **Page Interaction mode**, right next to the URL field. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13344637/1705383) is an explanation that should suffice.