# Test a page restricted by Forms Authentication for browser compatibility on Superpreview

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser, forms-authentication, superpreview

I have a set of pages that are authenticated using *Forms Authentication*. When I try to test such a page using ***SuperPreview*** and punch in the URL in the Url Location box, automatically the **Login** page comes up! One possible solution that comes off the head to me is to *disable* the authentication, but m sure one of you sharp guys out there have a *cleaner*(**better**) way to do it. So, how do I go about it??

**NOTE:** I am fairly new to SuperPreview and not fully acquainted with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impatient soul that I am, I went ahead to familiarize myself with SuperPreview and guess what! Right next to the **Url Location** is the **Page Interaction Mode** to help you login to those pages that require that. *Pretty neat yeah......*

[image: This is it!]